# How do I get a report of HD smart data in FreeBSD 7.x/8.x

Tags: hard-drive, freebsd, smart

Is there a simple way to convince FreeBSD 7.x or 8.x to give me SMART data on hard drives? Preferably from the command line since I normally run these systems as headless servers.
I've been spoiled by Ubuntu desktop which reports hard drive SMART data via System/Administration/Disk Utility applet...  but I'd rather not install Gnome on these FreeBSD systems if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
cd /usr/ports/sysutils/smartmontools/ && make install clean && rehash
smartctl -a /dev/ad0
```